# single schema but still nesting schema error is shown

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js

i am trying to build  login and registration system using node and passport
this is the schema

(models/user.js)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

//User Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        tye: String,
        index: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
        newUser.password = hash;
        newUser.save(callback);
    });
});
}
```

i have used only single schema `UserSchema`

the error is

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:646
    throw new TypeError('Undefined type `' + name + '` at `' + path +
    ^

TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at `username.index`
  Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
    at Function.Schema.interpretAsType (C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:646:11)
    at Schema.path (C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:502:29)
    at Schema.add (C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:383:12)
    at Schema.add (C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:372:14)
    at new Schema (C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:104:10)
    at Mongoose.Schema (C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:75:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\models\user.js:5:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\loginapp\routes\users.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

this is my routing file (routes/user.js)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var user = require('../models/user');

//Register
router.get('/register', function(req,res){
    res.render('register');
});

//Login
router.get('/login', function(req,res){
    res.render('login');
});

//Register User
router.post('/register', function(req,res){
   var name = req.body.name;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var password2 = req.body.password2;

    //Validation
    req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2', 'Password do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if(errors){
       res.render('register', {
           errors: errors
       });
    }
    else{
        var newUser = new User({
            name: name,
            email: email,
            username: username,
            password: password
        });
        User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(user);
        });

        req.flash('success_msg', 'You are registered and can now login');
        res.redirect('/users/login'); 
    }
});


module.exports = router;
```

i am unable to find the error
it says you have nested schemas so use refs but i have used only single schema
i am trying to build  login and registration system using node and passport
 cameit 
i am trying to build  login and registration system using node and passport
my app.js was perfectly working bu after including the schema the error cameit says you have nested schemas so use refs but i have used only single schema

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on the type declaration for `username`.

```
username: {
  tye: String, // typo here, should read 'type'
  index: true
},
```